# Подпрыгивает div при параллаксе

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, parallax

При создании параллакса, наткнулась на такую странность:
Последний (самый нижний) блок начинает подпрыгивать при прокручивании сайта в самый низ. Увидеть можно на примере.
Что это может быть?

Увеличение высоты блока .content или блока .body к решению проблемы не приводят. 
Увидела такую штуку - при единичном скролле колесика мыши, происходит смещение на 3-7 пикселей (случайно). По логам в консоли, вижу, что цифры отступов блоков всегда разнятся на те самые 3-7 пикселей. Но это не должно влиять, так как дойдя до конца страницы, дальше скроллить уже некуда.

Как остановить скачки?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 // Запрос функции паралакса при скролле
 $(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
     parallaxScroll();
 });


 // Создание адаптивности размера блоков на всю высоту для любого разрешения
 var div1Height = $('.div1').height();
        var div2Height = $('.div2').height();
 var div3Height = $('.div3').height();

 var div2Top = div1Height;
 $('.div2').css('top', div2Top);

 var div3Top = div2Top + div2Height;
 $('.div3').css('top', div3Top);

 div1Position = $('.div1').position().top; 
 div2Position = $('.div2').position().top;
 div3Position = $('.div3').position().top;
});
 
 
 //Создание эффекта параллакс
        var div1Position = 0;
        var div2Position = 0;
        var div3Position = 0;
        var scrolledAlbum = 0;
        var scrolledFooter = 0;

 function parallaxScroll(){
     var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

     if ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $('.div2').height() + $('.div2').offset().top) {

        if ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $('.div1').height() + $('.div1').offset().top) {
                  $('.div1').css('top', div1Position - scrolled * 0.95);
                  $('.div2').css('top', div2Position - scrolled * 0.95);
                  $('.div3').css('top', div3Position - scrolled * 0.95);
                  scrolledAlbum = scrolled;
        } else {
                  $('.div1').css('top', div1Position - scrolled * 0.95);
                  $('.div2').css('top', div2Position -scrolled*1.9 + scrolledAlbum);
                  $('.div3').css('top', div3Position -scrolled*1.9 + scrolledAlbum);
                  scrolledFooter = scrolled;
        }
     } else {
        $('.div1').css('top', div1Position - scrolled * 0.95);
        $('.div2').css('top', div2Position -scrolled*1.9 + scrolledAlbum);
        $('.div3').css('top', div3Position -scrolled*2.85 + scrolledAlbum + scrolledFooter);
     }
            $('.body').css('height', $('.div3').height() + $('.div3').position().top);
           
 }
```

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #000000;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 100%;
}

/* Content */

.bodyImage {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: url(https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/tekstura_treshchiny_chernyj_116899_1600x1200.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
}

.body {
        position: relative;
}

.div1 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background: #000000;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: 2;
}

.div2 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 text-align: center;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
 background: url(https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/tekstura_treshchiny_chernyj_116899_1600x1200.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
}

/* Footer */

.div3 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 4;
 background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>DECAY</title>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script|Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="content">
  
            <div class="bodyImage">
            </div>
   
            <div class="body">
               <div class="div1"> 
               </div>

               <div class="div2">
               </div>
  
               <div class="div3">
               </div>
            </div>

  </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Вы видимо некорректно добавили Ваш код `js`. 
Несколько переменных не объявлено. А данные `scrolledAlbum` и `scrolledFooter` в последнем `else` у Вас вообще не могут быть получены, так как в случае этого варианта их просто нет.

Comment: Да, не добавила `scrolledAlbum` и `scrolledFooter` при переносе кода на сайт. Исправлено. Но сути не меняет. Оно не работает как надо =). Касаемо необъявленных переменных. Они не объявлены потому, что не работали, когда я объявляла их через var. Зато когда просто записала данные в необъявленную переменную - оно все заработало (Это я про `div1Position`, `div2Position`, `div3Position`).

Comment: Мне просто нужно понять, почему оно так себя ведет. Я со всем дальше разберусь самостоятельно. Просто ничего в голову не приходит. Какая вообще может быть причина такого поведения?

Comment: Я объявила переменные `div1Position`, `div2Position`, `div3Position`. Стало на малость лучше, но блок все равно "колбасит". Не выдает ошибку только, когда объявляю их перед функцией параллакса. Возможно, дело именно в этом (в объявлении этих переменных). Но где мне их объявить? Если я объявляю их сразу после загрузки документа, консоль выдает, что такой переменной нет.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло добавление в `css` высоты для `div class="body"` равной `115vh`.